# Paypal Mass Payment Api get notification to non paypal email using Sandbox

Tags: php, paypal

I have used paypal mass payment api to pay commission. Right now i am using sandbox according to the documentation in mass payment api if we use non paypal email id then that user will get notification from paypa to create the account to get that payment but in my case no notification send via paypal to that non paypal email id.

How is it possible, any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

In Sandbox, the email is not send to the actual mailbox. The email only be send if the masspay is done on Live.

So, how you can have a proof that actually you are sending the money via masspay? You can try to create a sandbox account (any business or personal) using the email of the receiver (payer) and you can see the payment is being deposited.

Comment: Ok means when we use live credentials of paypal then it will works according to the paypal mas payment documentation and user will notify  by paypal to create the account if any email is non paypal  email.